# auto&& versus constrained auto&& in C++ templates

Tags: c++, c++20, forwarding-reference

MSVC /std:c++20 reports the error shown below for constrained auto&&

```
#include<concepts>

class Base { public: Base() {} };
class Derived : public Base { public: Derived() {} };

template<typename T> concept con = std::is_class_v<T>
&& std::derived_from<T, Base>;
void f(con auto&& x) {}

int main()
{
   f(Derived()); // r value: Ok

   Derived d;
   f(d); // l-value: no matching overloaded function found
}
```

Remove "con" from "con auto&&" and the above code compiles with no error.  I would like to understand why adding a constraint to an auto&& template parameter changes it from a "universal reference" to an R-value only reference. Does this behavior conform to the C++20 standard or is it something unique to MSVC?

Searched C++ forums on the internet and found nothing explaining this specific language use case.  However there may be something that I missed or otherwise did not notice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because on the instantiation with `Derived&` you'll be checking

```cpp
std::derived_from<Derived&, Base>
//              this guy ^
```

To make your concept immune to varying value categories, you can use `std::decay_t`:

```cpp
template<typename T> 
concept con = 
    std::is_class_v<std::decay_t<T>> && 
    std::derived_from<std::decay_t<T>, Base>;
```

so purely the types are checked w/o their value categories

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce2b3f96d67d8d29)

Comment: Thank for the quick response and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to understand why adding a constraint to an `auto&&` template parameter changes it from a "universal reference" to an R-value only reference.

It did not. The function parameter here is still a forwarding reference.

However, your constraint is requiring that the deduced type is (a) a class type (b) that is derived from `Base`. In the call `f(d)`, the template parameter deduces as `Derived&`, which is not a class type (nor is it derived from `Base`), so you've effectively made your function template only accept rvalues.

What you're looking for is

```cpp
template <class T>
    requires std::derived_from<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, Base>
void f(T&& x);
```

Or to put that `remove_cvref_t` in the concept definition.

Note that the `is_class` check is redundant. Only class types can derive from another type.

Comment: Thank for the quick response and detailed technical explanation.